# J2SE Java, is that possible to connect MySql database on other PC in same Connection?

Tags: java, php, mysql

i have database on my pc using MySql (XAMPP) and i create J2SE client server app, client side will work like login and update account, but all process is on same connection (LAN) is that possible client side to connect to server database ?

Comment: _is that possible client side to connect to server database_ yes, of-course it is possible, provided you can access server machine from client

Comment: @PradeepSimha, you mean if i can connect to server using ping or another LAN app, so i would to connect the database too ?